# Designing XamDataGrid ContextMenus

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I have a single window that can display one `XamDataGrid`. But, I plan to have several XamDataGrids to choose from:

1. PackagesGrid
2. ComponentsGrid
   etc.

Each such grid would have its own `DataSource` and `ContextMenu`. **The idea is to select a grid at run-time**. I'm wondering how I can design this.

Could I have `Styles` corresponding to each grid in my `ResourceDictionary` and then apply one to the single XamDataGrid in my Window at run-time? I'm not so experienced with WPF...can someone give me a few pointers to this or any other approach?

This is what I have so far:

### ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="XamDataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}">
</Style>
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="xamDataGrid1" Style={StaticResource XamDataGridStyle} />
```

Comment: It would be better to use a UserControl for each possible grid and then dynamically change which UserControl is the content on the Window (or or a content control within the Window).

Answer (score 0):

Use a content control with a ContentTemplateSelector:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

The ContentControl will be the placeholder for your grid content, and the content will be bound to your DataSource, which you will set at run time. You will implement some specific logic in the ContentTemplateSelector to return a specific DataTemplate (defined somewhere in your resources) that will contain specific grid control based on your content (dataSource).

This way you can create separate data templates for each grid type with their own context menus, etc, and have a uniform way of displaying them by dropping content controls.  The content controls will render the appropriate data template based on its content by using your ContentTemplateSelector logic.